# How to truncate text in TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am using `truncate` in TailwindCSS to make text ellipsis if text-overflow more than one line but it does not work.

My code not works below:

```
<div className="ml-1 inline-block">
   <span>Label: </span>
   <span className="font-semibold truncate">
     long texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
   </span>
</div>
```

**How can I fix It?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## UPDATE - LINE-CLAMP

tailwind now have line clamp plugin by default. so you can just use `line-clamp-1`

```
  <div className="ml-1 inline-block w-[200px]">
     <span>Label: </span>
     <span className="font-semibold line-clamp-1">
       long texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
     </span>
  </div>
```

## OLD ANSWER

First thing first your parent or the element must have a specific width otherwise how the element suppose to know when to stop and truncate? also in order to truncate to work your element's display must not be display `inline` since `span` is display inline by default you should change it to `block`

```
  <div className="ml-1 inline-block w-[200px]">
     <span>Label: </span>
     <span className="font-semibold line-clamp-1">
       long texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
     </span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 15):

Truncating in bare tailwind is pretty frustrating.
Please use this plugin instead

Install it from npm

```
npm install @tailwindcss/line-clamp
```

Then add it in tailwind.config.js file

```
plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/line-clamp')
  ],
```

To use it just add it as a class `className="line-clamp-1"`

Here is the documentation

https://tailwindcss.com/blog/multi-line-truncation-with-tailwindcss-line-clamp

Comment: Worked like a charm! Just to give my two cents, this plugin is not included by default when installing Tailwind, so you don't need to install it separately.

Answer (score 5):

In order not to set a fixed width of the element, you can simply specify the `min-width` of the parent block.

```
 <div className="ml-1 inline-block min-w-0">
         <span>Label: </span>
         <span className="font-semibold truncate block">
           long texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
         </span>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me share my experience in case it helps someone else to avoid the frustration. In my case the built-in `truncate` flag worked and the code looks like below:

```
<div  class="flex flex-row flex-shrink items-center gap-1 text-base font-medium whitespace-nowrap">
    <img class="w-5 h-4 flex-shrink-0"></img>
    <p class="truncate">
        Any potentially long long line here
    </p>
</div>
```

The `<img>` tag contains an icon, which I have omitted here. I have noticed that all examples from the Tailwind documentation use `<p>` tag for truncated text and **Tailwind documentation does not say specifically that the paragraph `<p>` tag is absolutely necessary for the `truncate` to work, but it seems to be the case here**.

Also please note that there is no need to set fixed width or specify min or max width or specify block display. But sometimes a parent element needs to specify `w-full` through depending on the structure of the other elements higher in the hierarchy.

Hope it helps.

Comment: truncate started to work when I changed from <div>TEXT</div> to <p>TEXT</p>, thx